# Cycle an iterator using multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, iterator, multiprocessing

I have an iterator that will retrive various number of lines from a very large (>20GB) file depend on some features. The iterator works fine, but I can only use 1 thread to process the result. I would like to feed the value from each iteration to multiple threads / processes.

I'm using a text file with 9 lines to mimic my data, here is my code. I've been struggling on how to create the feedback so when one process finished, it will go and retrive the next iteration:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import time

# Iterator
class read_file(object):
    def __init__(self, filePath):
        self.file = open(filePath, 'r')

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        line = self.file.readline()
        if line:
            return line
        else:
            raise StopIteration

# worker for one process
def print_worker(a, n, stat):
    print(a)
    stat[n] = True  # Set the finished status as True
    return None

# main
def main():
    file_path = 'tst_mp.txt'  # the txt file wit 9 lines
    n_worker = 2
    file_handle = read_file(file_path)
    workers = []
    
    # Create shared list for store dereplicated dict and progress counter
    manager = Manager()
    status = manager.list([False] * 2)  # list of dictonary for each thread
    
    # Initiate the workers
    for i in range(n_worker):
        workers.append(Process(target=print_worker, args=(file_handle.__next__(), i, status,)))
    for worker in workers:
        worker.start()
    
    block = file_handle.__next__() # The next block (line)
    while block:  # continue is there is still block left
        print(status)
        time.sleep(1)  # for every second
        for i in range(2):
            if status[i]:  # Worker i finished
                workers[i].join()
                # workers[i].close()
                workers[i] = Process(target=print_worker, args=(block, i, status,))
                status[i] = False  # Set worker i as busy (False)
                workers[i].start()  # Start worker i
                try:  # try to get the next item in the iterator
                    block = file_handle.__next__()
                except StopIteration:
                    block = False
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code is clumsy, but it did print out the sequence, but also with some error when I ran the code twice:

```
1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

Process Process-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zewei/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 802, in _callmethod
    conn = self._tls.connection
AttributeError: 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zewei/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/zewei/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/zewei/share/paf_depth/test_multiprocess.py", line 31, in print_worker
    stat[n] = True # Set the finished status as True
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/home/zewei/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 806, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "/home/zewei/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 794, in _connect
    dispatch(conn, None, 'accept_connection', (name,))
  File "/home/zewei/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 90, in dispatch
    kind, result = c.recv()
  File "/home/zewei/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 255, in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
  File "/home/zewei/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 419, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/home/zewei/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 384, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Here is where I'm stucked, I was wondering if there is any fix or more elegant way for this?

Thanks!

Comment: it turns out I have to ```join()``` all processes at the end of the code using ```join()```, but I would still like to know if there is a more elegant or phythonic way, thanks!

Comment: Don't call `__next__` manually. Just use a `for block in file_handle:`. For that matter, the value returned by `open` is *already* iterable; you don't need `read_file` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better way to do what you are doing, using pool:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

.
.
.
.

# worker for one process
def print_worker(a):
    print(a)
    return None

def main():
    file_path = r''  # the txt file wit 9 lines
    n_worker = 2
    file_handle = read_file(file_path)
    results = []

    with Pool(n_worker) as pool:
        for result in pool.imap(print_worker, file_handle):
            results.append(result)

        print(results)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here, the [`imap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) function lazily iterates over the iterator, so that the whole file won't be read into memory. Pool handles spreading the tasks across the number of processes you started (using `n_worker`) automatically so that you don't have to manage it yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I tested it, but it seems that the iterator will not continued until all workers finished the current process. I may have some iterations with heavy duty, but some with light duty. So I may stuck at some point where all other workers waiting for one to finish.

Comment: @ZeweiSong The iteration will not stop incase one worker is still busy, it will only stop incase **all** workers ae busy. So, you could try increasing `n_worker` value to spawn more workers, and additionally, set the `chunksize` parameter to a value greater than 1 in this line `pool.imap(print_worker, file_handle, chunksize=5)`. This will pass each worker more work by default each time it finishes the previous work.

Comment: Since `print_worker` returns `None` for all invocations, there isn't much value in saving these `None` results in `results` and therefore there is also no reason not to use method `imap_unordered`, which has less overhead.

Comment: @Booboo after changing ```imap``` to ```imap_unordered```, my code can run without stop, but I still need to think about it on how it works :D